# Wordpress search page in grid

Tags: wordpress, search, grid

I am doing a WordPress website, and want to show results in a grid with bootstrap. I want to show 3 results in each row, but it becomes messy. I can put col-Sm-4 which is keep repeating and it's ok, but I want that it puts class row also after each 3 results.
Is there any solution for this?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code code after you create that search.php file

<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
 * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
<section class="invoice-maker-page">
                <div class="invoice-maker-details">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="product-description">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyfifteen' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php
            // Start the loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                /*
                 * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
                 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                 * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', 'search' );

            // End the loop.
            endwhile;

            // Previous/next page navigation.
            the_posts_pagination( array(
                'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
            ) );
        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        else :
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
        endif;
        ?>
</div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


    </section><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```